# Laravel 5 : Undefined variable: post

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, undefined, crud, noclassdeffounderror

in my view, I got an error, Undefined variable: post (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/night-copy/resources/views/posts/index.blade.php).

I don't know why it happens. Please help me out.

I am creating a CRUD dashboard for admin side.

I will paste some of my codes, so if you need more codes, please ask me.

PostsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\Posts\CreatePostsRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Posts\UpdatePostRequest;
use App\Post;


class PostsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('posts.index')->with('posts', Post::all());
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }


    public function store(CreatePostsRequest $request)
    {
        //upload the image to strage
        //dd($request->image->store('posts'));
        $image = $request->image->store('posts');
        //create the posts
        Post::create([
            'image' => $image,
            'title' => $request->title,
            'place' => $request->place,
            'map' => $request->map,
            'date' => $request->date,
            'tag' => $request->tag,
            'description' => $request->description
        ]);
        //flash message
        session()->flash('success', 'Post created successfully.');
        //resirect user
        return redirect(route('posts.index'));
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        return view('posts.create')->with('post', $post);
    }

    public function update(UpdatePostRequest $request, Post $post)
    {
        $data = $request->only(['title', 'place', 'map', 'date', 'published_at', 'tag', 'description']);
        //check if new image
        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            //upload it
            $image = $request->image->store('posts');
            //delete old image
            $post->deleteImage();
            $data['image'] = $image;
        }
        //update attributes
        $post->update($data);
        //flash message
        session()->flash('success', 'Post updated sucessfully.');
        //redirect user
        return redirect(route('posts.index'));
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = Post::withTrashed()->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
        if($post->trashed()) {
            $post->deleteImage();
            $post->forceDelete();
        } else {
            $post->delete();
        }
        session()->flash('success', 'Post deleted successfully.');
        return redirect(route('posts.index'));
    }

    public function trashed()
    {
        $trashed = Post::onlyTrashed()->get();
        return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $trashed);
    }

    public function restore($id)
    {
        $post = Post::withTrashed()->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
        $post->restore();
        session()->flash('success', 'Post restore successfully.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

index.blade.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/main-posts.css') }}">
    <title>Event Confirmation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h2 class="logo">Dark Code</h2>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
                <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color: white;"></i>
                </label>
            <ul class="menu">
                <div class="menu-list">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" ></i></a>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                    <a href="{{ route('posts.index') }}">Post</a>
                    <a href="{{ route('categories.index') }}">Category</a>
                    <a href="{{ route('trashed-posts.index') }}">Suspended</a>
                    <a href="#">Logout</a>
                    <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
                        <i class="fas fa-times" style="color: white;"></i>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="userinfo">
                    <div class="content"> 
                        @if($posts->count() > 0)
                        <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Location</th>   
                        <th>Map</th>   
                        <th>Date</th>   
                        <th>Tags</th>           
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($posts as $post)
                        <tr></tr>
                        <td>{{ $post->id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>    
                        <td>{{ $post->place }}</td>    
                        <td>{{ $post->map }}</td>     
                        <td>{{ $post->date }}</td> 
                        <td>{{ $post->tag }}</td>

                        @if($post->trashed())
                        <form action="{{ route('restore-posts', $post->id) }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')
                        <button class="save-btn" type="submit">Restore</button>
                        </form>
                        <br>
                        @else
                        <button btn="" class="edit-btn">
                            <a href="{{ route('posts.edit', $post->id) }}">Edit</a>
                        </button><br>
                        @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <form action="{{ route('posts.destroy', $post->id) }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button type="submit" class="delete-btn" >
                            {{ $post->trashed() ? 'Delete' : 'Trash' }}
                        </button><br>
                        </form>
                        </td>    
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                        @else
                        <h3 style="margin: 15rem; color: white;">No Posts Yet</h3>
                        @endif
                        </div>   
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        @if($post->trashed())
        @else
        <a href="{{ route('posts.create') }}"><button btn="" class="add-btn">Add</button></a>
        @endif
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::get('trashed-posts', 'PostsController@trashed')->name('trashed-posts.index');
Route::PUT('restore-post/{post}', 'PostsController@restore')->name('restore-posts');
```

Comment: Can you post your full view please?

Comment: @nakov I added my full index.blade.php, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, you're calling `@if($post->trashed())` outside of `@endforeach` block so the `$post` is outside the scope by then and hence undefined variable.
Besides the `@if` statement there is redundant, you want the user to be able to create a new post regardless whether a specific post is trashed or not

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="userinfo">
        <div class="content">
            @if($posts->count() > 0)
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Map</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Tags</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($posts as $post)
                    <tr></tr>
                    <td>{{ $post->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $post->place }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $post->map }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $post->date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $post->tag }}</td>

                    @if($post->trashed())
                    <form action="{{ route('restore-posts', $post->id) }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')
                        <button class="save-btn" type="submit">Restore</button>
                    </form>
                    <br>
                    @else
                    <button btn="" class="edit-btn">
                        <a href="{{ route('posts.edit', $post->id) }}">Edit</a>
                    </button><br>
                    @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{{ route('posts.destroy', $post->id) }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')
                            <button type="submit" class="delete-btn">
                                {{ $post->trashed() ? 'Delete' : 'Trash' }}
                            </button><br>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            @else
            <h3 style="margin: 15rem; color: white;">No Posts Yet</h3>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<a href="{{ route('posts.create') }}"><button btn="" class="add-btn">Add</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view file Check this line `@if($post->trashed())`. this is outside of foreach loop. comment this line out or remove it